# How to check per user license in SharePoint Add-ins

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to check the per user license in my SharePoint add-ins. I follow [this link](https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/license-your-add-ins#bk_anonymous) here they mention that **If the user is not signed in to their Microsoft account, the Office application requesting the add-in home page does not append the license token parameter**.

I want to check per user license. So How can I check the user license in my Add-in. How signed in to their Microsoft account will work in that case. Please suggest me how can I get this license token in my add-in.

Currently I am not able to get the license token in my Add-in.